# Encountering Error While Establishing a Relationship in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys, migration, relationship

I want to create a migration in the project that I want to develop with ASP Net Core, but I am getting the error I added below. I also added entities. Can you help me ?

> Unable to create an object of type 'RepositoryContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

I changed the startup project to data access and made sure the data access layer was selected in the package manager console.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Apartment
{
    public DateOnly ConstructionDate { get; set; }
    public List<Home> Homes { get; set; }
    public List<HomeOwner> HomeOwners { get; set; }
}

public class Home
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public HomeOwner HomeOwner { get; set; }
}

public class HomeOwner
{
    public string HomeOwnerName { get; set; }
    public string HomeOwnerLastName { get; set; }
    public string HomeOwnerPhone { get; set; }
    public string HomeOwnerEmail { get; set; }
    public string HomeOwnerAddress { get; set; }
    public Home Home { get; set; }
    public int HomeId { get; set; }
    public Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public int ApartmentId { get; set; }
    public Apartment Apartment { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant : BaseEntity
{
    public string TenantName { get; set; }
    public string TenantLastName { get; set; }
    public string TenantPhone { get; set; }
    public string TenantEmail { get; set; }
    public string TenantAddress { get; set; }
    public DateOnly TenantMovingDate { get; set; }
    public Home Home { get; set; }
}

public class RepositoryContext : DbContext
{
    public RepositoryContext(DbContextOptions<RepositoryContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("DataSource=DESKTOP-9MDCD3N;Initial Catalog=ApartmentManagementAppDb;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
    }

    public DbSet<Home> Homes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<HomeOwner> HomeOwners { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tenant> Tenants { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Apartment> Apartments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Don't change the startup project. Whatever your startup project was, keep it. Instead, use `--startup-project StartupName --project DalName`.

Comment: unfortunately nothing has changed

Comment: The issue isn't related to the code you posted, but to the DbContext configuration and how you're running the migration, which we have no information on.

Comment: You need `optionsBuilder.IsConfigured` check, otherwise migrations cannot control connection string.

Comment: Im tried your comments but nothing changed